# Splitting a string from a larger string from the start in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I want to split a string of numbers from a larger string of numbers from the start of the larger string. For the following Regex:

```
string[] s = Regex.Split(t.S1, t.S40);
```

Here are the inputs and outputs I'm looking for:

1. When t.S1 = "101" and t.S40 = "1", the result should be "01"
2. When t.S1 = "1010221" and t.S40 = "10102", the result should be "21".

Also, is there any way for the result to be a `string` instead of a `string[]` ?

Comment: For the first case string[ ] returns as
string s[0] = ""
string s[1] = "0"
string s[2] = ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really related to regex at all...

From your examples, I can't tell if you want to remove *all* occurrences of `S2`, just the first it finds, or only if it's at the very beginning.

In any case, this code will remove the first occurrence:

```
const string S1 = "1010221";
const string S2 = "10102";

String result = S1;
if (S1.Contains(S2))
    result = S1.Remove(S1.IndexOf(S2), S2.Length);
```

All occurrences:

```
String result = S1;
if (S1.Contains(S2))
    result = S1.Replace(S2, String.Empty);
```

And only if at the start:

```
String result = S1;
if (S1.StartsWith(S2))
    result = S1.Replace(S2, String.Empty);
```

Remove only first occurrence and only if it's at the start:

```
String result = S1;
if (S1.StartsWith(S2))
    result = S1.Remove(S1.IndexOf(S2), S2.Length);
```

And yes, these will return `string`, not `string[]`

Comment: I want to remove it only from the start. But when I used your code. It results in "0" for the first case.

Answer (score 3):

`String.Substring` seems to be the solution:

```
string s1 = "1010221";
string s2 = "10102";

string result = s1.Substring(s2.Length); // 21
```